# How can I stop various nodes on SpriteKit and then resume its move?

Tags: sprite-kit

I need stop various nodes which is moving on the screen, and then resume its move. I searched stop, and paused method but not exits.

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you search? Because a `paused` property exists.

> **paused** 
>   A Boolean value that determines whether actions on the node and
>   its descendants are processed.
>
> `@property(getter=isPaused, nonatomic) BOOL paused` 
>   **Discussion** 
>   If the
>   value is YES, the node (and all of its descendants) are skipped when a
>   scene processes actions.

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH MUCH MUCH, sorry for my idiot question (and my english too) I´m a beginner in programming.